# get the user only 100 rows from database that he hasn't seen yet

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, nosql

I need any kind of DB that will be able to do my task which is to know if there is any way to grab only data that the user hasn't pulled from the databases yet for example:
I have a user that pulls 5 country names from the database each time, and when he finishes viewing them I want him to get 5 more country names that he didn't pull till now.
can you help me find a way to do it?

*sorry for my English

Comment: The functionality you need can be achieved with most databases. You'll want to search using the name of the database you're using "<postgresql, mysql, etc. whatever you have> sql pagination".

Comment: Hi, I see how it does the limit to 5 for example but I can't find the way to prevent from that 5 not include one of the other 5's I already pulled.

Comment: `LIMIT` can be followed by two parameters, in which case the first one is the starting row and the second one the number of rows to return.  See here: https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is ordered results:

```
select id, name from country where id > @highest_id_so_far order by id limit 5;
```

Start with a negative @highest_id_so_far. You get the first entries, say, IDs 1, 4, 5, 6, 7.

The highest ID returned was 7, so query with @highest_id_so_far = 7 then and you get the next five rows (e.g. 8, 10, 12, 23, 24). And so on.